# sum of total present values in a row in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

attendance table

```
id name 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 month year

 1 abcd P P P HOLIDAY P P P P P P HOLIDAY P P P P P P HOLIDAY P P P P P P HOLIDAY P P P P P P 01 2014
```

you can see above is a attendance table. a member abcd has attended all days in January month. so her total present days in January month is 27.

so in this table i want to add another field which will show total present days of the member of a particular month.

please tell me how can i count the number of present day (P) from this table.

```
CREATE TABLE `attendance` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `Ecode` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `Ename` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `01` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `02` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `03` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `04` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `05` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `06` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `07` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `08` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `09` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `10` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `11` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `12` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `13` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `14` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `15` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `16` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `17` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `18` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `19` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `20` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `21` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `22` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `23` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `24` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `25` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `26` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `27` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `28` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `29` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `30` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `31` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `total_p` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `total_sl` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `total_al` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `month` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `year` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: no, we can't see... your "table" makes no sense.

Comment: how can i show you... is there another technique...

Comment: Don’t store your data like that, make it individual records of the format `id|name|date|attended` instead.

Comment: a table named "attendance" has the field like membername,day1today31,month,year. if a member is present on a particular day then 'P' is automaticaly marked.so i want the sum of total (P)s in that month.

Comment: It looks to me like each row of your table contains a total of 35 columns. They are `id, name, 1, 2, ... 31, month, year`.  Is that correct? It looks to me like each of the columns whose name is a number can contain "P" for present, "HOLIDAY", or something else for absent. Is that correct?  What does a row for February look like? April? How do you handle leap years?

Comment: it doesn't matter if 28 days are only filled in february month.. i only want sum of present day

Comment: @user3270121 your data format is fine, I have posted the answer below on how to count present days.

Comment: I seriously advice you change your database structure as `CREATE TABLE `attendance` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `Day_Number` varchar(200) NOT NULL, `STATUS` varchar(10) NOT NULL, etc) where this should be a child table and your parent table contains id and name and code

Answer (score 1):

Your table definition will look something like this.

```
CREATE TABLE `attendance` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) ,
  `1` VARCHAR(10),
  `2` VARCHAR(10),
  `3` VARCHAR(10),
    ...
  `31` VARCHAR(10),
  `month` INT(11),
  `year` INT(11),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Your p-counter expression will look like this in SQL

```
SELECT name,
       IF(`1`='P',1,0)+IF(`2`='P',1,0)+IF(`3`='P',1,0)+IF(`4`='P',1,0)+
        etc. etc. +IF(`31`='P',1,0) AS pcount,
       month,
       year
  FROM attendance
```

If this looks like a nasty expression, that's because it is.  I hope you understand what a genuinely difficult-to-maintain table definition this is.

**Edit**
One row per person per day would work much better. The attendance table might look like this:

```
 id          int
 name        varchar
 day         DATE
 attendance  varchar(10)
```

Then you could produce a report showing monthly attendance using conventional SQL aggregate reporting, something like this.

```
SELECT name, 
       DATE_FORMAT('%Y-%m-01') AS month_beginning,
       SUM(IF(attendance = 'P', 1, 0)) AS days_present
  FROM attendance
 GROUP BY name, DATE_FORMAT('%Y-%m-01')
 ORDER BY name, DATE_FORMAT('%Y-%m-01')
```

Comment: Ollie Jones thank you very much. if you have a time please give me an example of proper table definition for attendance system so it wil be helpfull to me in future... again thank you very much....

Comment: Suggest OP to change db structure

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to stack overflow!

Yes there may be a better way to store your data, but it is easy to solve your problem.  I am going to assume you already know how to get your $row variable, if not just leave a comment and I will tell you how.  Having said that, the code goes like this:

```
$attendance = 0;

for ($index = 1;index <= 31;index++) {
    if ($row[' . strval($index) . '] === "P") {
        $attendance++;
    }
}

echo "Attendance is " . strval($attendance) . " days";
```

Answer (score 0):

since i cant post a comment yet (bec. of required reputation) ill just post my suggestion here,

can you please show us the structure of your table? Try this command and kindly post the output.

```
  SHOW CREATE TABLE 'your attendance table Name'
```

---

(UPDATES) you need to change you table structure, you can create something like this, not normalize, but at least maybe this can help you.

```
 CREATE TABLE `attendance` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `Ecode` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
   `Ename` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   `date`  DATE NOT NULL,
   `status` char(1) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

at `status` field, you try use P - present, H - holiday, A- absent... 
and your attendance table will look like this:

```
   ------------------------------------------------
     id  | Ecode | Ename    |  date     | status |
   -----------------------------------------------
     1   | code1 | Jane Doe |2014-01-05 | P
   -----------------------------------------------
     2   | code1 | Jane Doe |2014-01-06 | A   
   ----------------------------------------------
   ...
```

Then, you can query something like this:

```
 SELECT Ecode, Ename, count(status)  as numberOfpresent
 FROM attendance WHERE status = 'P'
 GROUP By Ecode;
```

Comment: youre welcome but you need to change your table structure,. ill update my post